# Paypal plus Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, ce-1.9.2.2

I have installed PayPal plus extension from Iways, on magento version 1.9.2.2. Locally works everything fine, on  my dev environment I receive the error

> Provided credentials not valid.
>   Webhook creation failed.

I have sandbox account everything is ok. I have checked the client id and the Secret key, no errors. The lib folder from the extension is also there.
I really don't understand why I receive this error that the credentials are not valid.

Anybody any other idea, I will appreciate.

Comment: try the latest version https://github.com/kgoedecke/magento-paypal-plus-extension

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has gone away itself (read comment at answer).

Comment: Guys, any extension of paypal plus for magento 1?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it as followed:

In my php pool configuration, I added the following command to secure my php:

> php_admin_value[disable_functions] =
>   dl,exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source

After that I get the same error:
**Provided credentials not valid.
Webhook creation failed.**

I changed it in:

> php_admin_value[disable_functions] =
>   dl,exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source

after that I restarted my php service:

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

and flushed the Magento cache, this worked for me, I hope this solve your problem too.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

The problem was with the Server configuration. An old curl version. It doesn't work with curl 7.19. Recommendation curl > 7.36.